# DIMM slot usage for 2x8GB RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard

Please let me know if this is the wrong community to ask this question, it seemed the best match to me.

I recently built a new PC and have been running Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.7.3 (upgraded from 4.5.x). It has been having problems (fatally freezing every few days) from the beginning and I have been trying to debug it.

I burned a memtest86 usb and have been running the memory tests to check for errors and have noticed some erratic behavior and wanted to see if others have had this problem as well.

I have 2x8GB 2400MHz Viper RAM cards (default settings in UEFI) and I noticed that certain placements of the cards in the 4 available DIMM slots cause serious errors. Now the manual for my motherboard (Asus Z170-AR) has three "Recommended Memory Configurations" which I've taken a picture of: [Dimm Slot Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLfuC.jpg)  there are no other instructions on compatibility.

When I use a memory configuration other than the "recommended", SOME of those configurations will result in the memtest86 giving thousands of errors and even sometimes freezing up and crashing the memtest, forcing me to restart. for example, one ram card in A1 or A3 or A4 gives no errors, but one ram card in A2 will give thousands of errors, etc....

Is this normal behavior? It seems as though the motherboard manual would explicit tell the user to ONLY use such configurations if using anything else could cause such fatal errors. The inconsistency of the occurrences of these errors had me wondering if my motherboard could have defective dimm slots, or if getting such serious amounts of memory errors is normal when not using the "recommended" configurations.

This was a pricey motherboard so I'd like to swap it for a functional if there is a chance that some of the memory slots are defective.

Comment: It sounds like slot A2 is bad. I would RMA the board. When testing RAM with memtest you generally start with your original setup. If you get errors, I tend to test one stick at a time in A0. If all sticks pass in A0, I use a single stick and change slots after each test run. If I still happen to have no errors I'll then test each channel combination one at a time.

Comment: Okay thanks for the input, i've been seeing a lot of contradictory information so I think I'll bring it back just for safety's sake